# Como o Laravel faz para fazer a leitura do arquivo ".env"?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, biblioteca

Como o Laravel faz para fazer a leitura do arquivo ".env"?

Já olhei nos repositórios do `Illuminate` (do Laravel) e não achei nada que me desse uma dica de como a leitura esse arquivo fosse feita.

Existe alguma biblioteca, que o Laravel usa, que faça isso? E se tem, qual é o nome?

Comment: Procure por **Dotenv** no projeto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tem uma biblioteca chamada [`vlucas/phpdotenv`](https://packagist.org/packages/vlucas/phpdotenv) que tem essa responsabilidade em fazer a leitura do arquivo `.env`.

No `composer.json` do [Laravel](https://www.laravel.com) tem essa configuração do pacote.

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.6.4",
    "ext-mbstring": "*",
    "ext-openssl": "*",
    "classpreloader/classpreloader": "~3.0",
    "doctrine/inflector": "~1.0",
    "jeremeamia/superclosure": "~2.2",
    "league/flysystem": "~1.0",
    "monolog/monolog": "~1.11",
    "mtdowling/cron-expression": "~1.0",
    "nesbot/carbon": "~1.20",
    "paragonie/random_compat": "~1.4|~2.0",
    "psy/psysh": "0.7.*",
    "ramsey/uuid": "~3.0",
    "swiftmailer/swiftmailer": "~5.1",
    "symfony/console": "3.1.*",
    "symfony/debug": "3.1.*",
    "symfony/finder": "3.1.*",
    "symfony/http-foundation": "3.1.*",
    "symfony/http-kernel": "3.1.*",
    "symfony/process": "3.1.*",
    "symfony/routing": "3.1.*",
    "symfony/translation": "3.1.*",
    "symfony/var-dumper": "3.1.*",
    "vlucas/phpdotenv": "~2.2"
},
```

No Laravel em especifico a sua utilização seria feita o carregamento do arquivo na `classe Application` no método logo abaixo:

```
/**
 * Register a callback to run after loading the environment.
 *
 * @param  \Closure  $callback
 * @return void
 */
public function afterLoadingEnvironment(Closure $callback)
{
    return $this->afterBootstrapping(
        'Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\DetectEnvironment', $callback
    );
}
```

tem outros métodos relacionados também, mas, esse sendo o principal.

Comment: Bacana, essa resposta será bastante útil para quem desejar usar o Dotenv fora de um projeto Laravel :p

Comment: Estou ainda procurando aonde é feito a leitura no `Laravel` se achar já edito.

Comment: Descobri. A classe é `Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\DetectEnvironment`.

Comment: Ai é o arquivo criado para fazer a chamada, mas, quem chama mesmo é na `class Application`

Comment: Valeu pela resposta, jovem.