# Utilizar o arquivo .env no projeto PHP?

Tags: php

Percebi que no `Laravel` usa o arquivo `.env` para algumas configurações e no código ele uma função `env()`, pergunto:

- Existe alguma forma de utilizar o arquivo `.env` no meu projeto `php` sem usar algum `framework`?
- Se sim, como?

Comment: `getenv()` seria o nome correto da função.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A título de curiosidade, informo que a Biblioteca utilizada para fazer a leitura desse arquivo `.env` chama-se [vLucas/phpdotenv](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv) e pode ser instalada via [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/). Sendo assim, você pode implementar ela em qualquer projeto, desde que configure-a corretamente.

Por exemplo:

1 - Crie uma pasta para testar a biblioteca.

```
mkdir test_env
```

2 - Em seguida selecione essa pasta e instale o `vlucas/phpdotenv` através do Composer:

```
curl -s http://getcomposer.org/installer | php

php composer.phar require vlucas/phpdotenv
```

3 - Crie seu arquivo `.env` na mesma pasta.

```
#.env
PROJECT_NAME="Test Env"
```

4 - Crie um arquivo `index.php`

```
// Esse arquivo e pasta é gerado depois de instalação da biblioteca descrita acima
include_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$dotenv = new Dotenv\Dotenv(__DIR__);
$dotenv->load();

var_dump(getenv('PROJECT_NAME'));
var_dump($_ENV['PROJECT_NAME']);
```

Creio que parte dessa pergunta já se encontra respondida aqui:

- [Como o Laravel faz para fazer a leitura do arquivo ".env"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/155977/como-o-laravel-faz-para-fazer-a-leitura-do-arquivo-env/155988#155988)

Comment: Deu `Fatal error: Call to undefined function env() in D:\wamp\www\testeenv\index.php on line 9
Call Stack`

Comment: @adventistaam eu acho que errei nesse ponto, tente `getenv` por gentileza.

Comment: @adventistaam era exatamente isso. O correto é `getenv`

Comment: agora sim deu certo

Comment: como estou usando no windows a linha com o comando `curl -s http ...` não deu certo, mas usei o comando `php -r "readfile('https://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php` e consegui continuar

Comment: Outra opção que encontrei ser bem mais robusta é [symfony dotenv](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dotenv.html).

Answer (score 12):

### Arquivos com extensão arbitrária

Alguns sistemas/frameworks podem eleger arquivos texto com extensões arbitrárias como `.env`, `.ini`, `.config` e outras, isto não faz destes arquivos nada em especial, é mera convenção, e deve ser tratado caso a caso.

No caso do Laravel, o arquivo `.env` é mera configuração, um arquivo texto normal, sem nada em especial, que fica usualmente no diretório `config`, e é usado complementarmente (sendo carregado no ambiente por uma função própria).

Veja na resposta do @GuilhermeNascimento um exemplo de como usar o `parse_ini_file` para a parte de leitura do arquivo, e na resposta do @Wallace mais detalhes sobre o projeto que mencionei logo abaixo.

A idéia aqui é que ao colocar algumas informações no ambiente, você está protegendo sua aplicação (exemplo: credenciais de acesso que não estejam num arquivo texto, protegidas de cópias acidentais), e tendo outras menos sensíveis em arquivos convencionais para facilitar cópia e migração.

O @bfavaretto disse nos comentários sobre [esse](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv) projeto no GitHub que carrega as variáveis de arquivos `.env` no ambiente do sistema, para mesclar o uso do arquivo `.env` com as variáveis do ambiente, deixando em arquivo o que for menos sensível, e configurando diretamente no sistema coisas que não devem ser copiadas, mas...

...**muito melhor que isso,** até pra não criar dependência de repositórios de terceiros para uma coisa tão básica, é usar as funções nativas do PHP:

### Utilizando o ambiente com `$_ENV`

Para acessar dados do ambiente basta usar a variável especial

```
$_ENV
```

(antigamente era `$HTTP_ENV_VARS`, que está obsoleta. `$_ENV` é a maneira "moderna")

Ela funciona de maneira análoga ao `$_GET`, `$_POST` etc.

Exemplo:

Se no seu ambiente você tem isto:

```
PATH=/root
```

ao usar

```
$caminho = $_ENV['PATH'];
echo $caminho;
```

obterá `"/root"`

### Usando `getenv()`

A função `getenv()` se preza para o mesmo. Veja o código equivalente ao anterior, usando a função em vez de variável pré-populada:

```
$caminho = getenv('PATH');
echo $caminho;
```

### Alterando um valor no ambiente com `putenv()`

A função `putenv()` permite que você altere/defina um valor no ambiente, sempre lembrando que vale para a sessão atual. Se quiser alterações permanentes, precisa usar os recursos do OS (ou no caso do Laravel, editar o arquivo .env)

### Documentação:

> http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.environment.php
>
> http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.getenv.php
>
> http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.putenv.php

Comment: ele diz que está obsoleta

Comment: Não está. Leia o manual linkado . De qq forma, atualizei para esclarecer.

Comment: Pelo que vi, o Laravel usa o .env com isto https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv

Comment: Existe uma forma de eu usar um arquivo .env também?

Comment: Incorporei o link do @bfavaretto na resposta, creio que ele resolve para que você use .env nos seus projetos com as funções acima, sem precisar escrever código próprio para isto.

Answer (score 9):

Creio que, se é sem o uso de frameworks, também está considerando não usar bibliotecas externas. Então, você fazer um parse do `.ini` com [`parse_ini_file`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php) (que na verdade pode ter qualquer extensão) que é **bem semelhante**, por exemplo:

```
$parsed = parse_ini_file('config/foo.env');
```

Se o conteudo do arquivo for:

```
; Comentários começam com ';'

[database]
mysql_host = foo.com
mysql_login = baz
mysql_pass = foobarbaz

[debug]
enable = false
error_level = 32767 ; = E_ALL

[requirements]
phpversion[] = "5.6"
phpversion[] = "7.0"
phpversion[] = "7.1"
phpversion[] = "7.2"
```

Irá gerar isto (sem as "sessões"):

```
Array
(
    [mysql_host] => foo.com
    [mysql_login] => baz
    [mysql_pass] => foobarbaz
    [enable] => 0
    [error_level] => 32767
    [phpversion] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5.6
            [1] => 7.0
            [2] => 7.1
            [3] => 7.2
        )

)
```

Acaso deseje usar as sessões adicione o `true`:

```
$parsed = parse_ini_file('config/foo.env', true);
```

Irá gerar isto:

```
Array
(
    [database] => Array
        (
            [mysql_host] => foo.com
            [mysql_login] => baz
            [mysql_pass] => foobarbaz
        )

    [debug] => Array
        (
            [enable] => 0
            [error_level] => 32767
        )

    [requirements] => Array
        (
            [phpversion] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 5.0
                    [1] => 5.1
                    [2] => 5.2
                    [3] => 5.3
                )
        )
)
```

Claro que não é obrigatório usar o `$_ENV`, o Laravel usa quando a aplicação faz um requeste, adicionando os valores do `.env`, mas eu pessoalmente penso que isso é opcional, ainda sim se desejar fazer pode usar desta maneira:

```
$envs = parse_ini_file('config/foo.env');

foreach ($envs as $key => $value) {
    $_ENV[$key] = $value;
}
```

Claro que vai ficar só disponível dentro do script principal e após executar isso, mas não vejo muito porque usar além disto.

Outra opção que acho que pode até ser um pouco mais simples, seria apenas usar uma função:

```
function MeuEnv($chave)
{
     static $envs;

     if (!$envs) {
          $envs = parse_ini_file('config/foo.env');
     }

     return empty($envs[$chave]) ? null : $envs[$chave];
}
```

E o uso ficaria assim:

```
var_dump(MeuEnv('mysql_host'), MeuEnv('mysql_login'));
```

### Recomendação

Eu realmente recomendo que não permita que arquivos assim fiquem acessíveis publicamente, o próprio Laravel é seguro em si, mas muita gente ao invés de apontar pelo *VirtualHost* para a pasta `public` dele apenas movem para `public_html/public` ou `www/public` e criam um `.htaccess` que reescreve a URL, até ai tudo bem, talvez não seja acessivel externamente, mas se o .htaccess for mal configurado conteudo isto:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Os arquivos ficarão expostos, isso pode ocorrer no seu projeto também, então recomendo que tome cuidado com isto e se possivel mantenha os seus `.env` fora da pasta root do seu servidor (geralmente `public_html`, `www`) e se puder também só permita a leitura e manuseio do arquivo para o usuário do sistema operacional que realmente ajustar estes arquivos, então nunca use permissões como `777`.

Comment: O objeto é deixar as configurações do banco fora dos commits, e essa aí é uma ótima solução

Comment: @adventistaam só recomendo que coloque arquivos com dados sensiveis, como autenticação de banco em uma pasta que não seja acessivel publicamente via HTTP ;)

Comment: Entendi. Isso é muito importante

Comment: Nessa [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/98991/4995) eu expliquei bastante coisa a respeito de configurações. Vale a pena dar uma olhada.

Comment: Por que eu usaria uma lib para fazer leitura de um arquivo `.env` se é tão simples fazer desta forma que passou?

Comment: Concordo contigo @rbz, a minha maior critica sobre as comunidades PHP e JavaScript (com NPM) é justamente essa, e a sua pergunta (que provavelmente é retórica) responde muito bem, não existe vantagem quando realmente é algo simples assim, a unica motivação que seria para usar o phpdotenv seria para usar os métodos auxiliares e também manter compatibilidade com .env de outros projetos, aonde os comentários usam "#" vão acabar sendo passados como valores https://ideone.com/YjyOIn ...

Comment: ... no entanto não vejo problema nisso, já que se existir um valor com # como chave você só acessaria se necessário, então acaba que parse_ini também atende

Comment: Esta deveria ser a melhor resposta.